# How to apply a filter to a .jpg image using only NumPy and PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, convolution

I am trying to apply the following blur filter `np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])/9` to a .jpg image, however, the image is coming out either all black or with strange colours.

I don't understand what I'm getting wrong because I applied a greyscale filter and it worked. The process was as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

image = Image.open('sample.jpg')

data = asarray(image)

gray = np.dot(data, [0.3,0.59,0.11]) 
gray = gray.astype(np.uint8) 
img = Image.fromarray(gray) 
img.save('sample.png')
```

Why isn't this working with other filters? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Applying the filter makes the image values floats (decimals), but then you cast the image to unsigned 8-bit integers (`gray.astype(np.uint8)`). This will truncate all of the decimals to integers.